# how to turn an array into an object of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'd like this array:

```
const myArr = ['lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit', 'amet']
```

to change into an object that would look like this:

```
{
  lorem:{
    ipsum:{
       dolor:{
         sit:{
           amet: ''
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: What did you try and where/how did it fail?

Comment: The thing is I don't know how to start solving it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const result = myArr.reduceRight((accumulator, currentValue) => {
  return {
    [currentValue]: accumulator
  };
}, '');
```

If you want, you can shorten the syntax:

```
const result = myArr.reduceRight((accumulator, currentValue) => 
  ({[currentValue]: accumulator}), '');
```

Comment: @Magda, no problem. If you feel the answer is correct, I'd appreciate it if you'd mark it as such.